# How do I override defaults settings in featherlight?

Tags: javascript, jquery, featherlight.js

Featherlight works with no problems but I cannot figure out how to override defaults settings.

I read the documentation, but everything I try does not seems to work. For example, if I want to change `openSpeed`, what should I write? I am not using the gallery.

[Featherlight configuration docs](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight#configuration).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just modify properties of `$.featherlight.defaults`, like this:

```
$.featherlight.defaults.openSpeed = 500;
```

As @Marc-AndréLafortune pointed, you can override multiple options using `$.extend()`, like that:

```
$.extend($.featherlight.defaults, {
  openSpeed: 1000,
  closeSpeed: 1000
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change the default globally with

```
$.featherlight.defaults.openSpeed = 1000
```

For multiple settings, you can of course use:

```
$.extend($.featherlight.defaults, {
  openSpeed: 1000,
  closeSpeed: 1000
});
```

Just don't replace the defaults by a different object altogether.